# phpMailer plesk centos multiple IP setup

Tags: php, email, centos, phpmailer, plesk

I have a Plesk centos 6 cloud server that runs two domains on two different IPs. One of the domains has subdomains which send emails out via phpMailer, through a designated smtp server, in the case at hand, gmail.

Although I don't believe the problem lies or can be mitigated at the level of executing phpMailer, here is an example of that to demonstrate:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPDebug = false;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Username = $GLOBALS['gmail'];
$mail->Password = $GLOBALS['email_password'];
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->From = $GLOBALS['gmail'];
$mail->FromName = $GLOBALS['sender'];
$mail->addReplyTo($GLOBALS['gmail'], "Reply");
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->addAddress($this->data['Email']); 
$mail->Subject = "...";
$mail->Body = "...";
$mail->Send();
```

Now I see within the Smart Network Data Service at postmaster.live.com that both IPs have been blocked due to evidence of spamming.

Investigating I found what I suspect is the problem - that in the *Received* part of the email header, the sending subdomain is identified correctly by name, but the sending IP address is that of the other domain. Like this:

Received: from *correct subdomain.domain.com* (**incorrect reverseDNS domain** [**incorrect IP**])  by smtp.gmail.com ...

It appears that phpMailer has connected to smtp.gmail.com from the wrong IP address, with the result that the reverseDNS lookup resolves to that of the other domain – and this is likely what Microsoft have picked up on.

Within Plesk (Tools & Tettings -> IP Addresses), the IP of what should be the correct domain is listed first, and is bold, suggesting that should be the default.

UPDATE:
Now I tried:

```
        $options = array(
            'socket' => array(
                'bindto' => '**the required IP**',
            ),
        );
        $socket_context = stream_context_create($options);
        $this->smtp_conn = stream_socket_client(
                        $host . ":" . $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $socket_context
        );
```

This produced the following error, which narrows the problem specifically to not being able to bind the IP associated with the domain:

**PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): failed to bind to '*domainIP*:587', system said: Permission denied**

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Which IP is used for outbound to any particular destination is handled by the default routes defined in your server's networking config. You're right in that it's generally not something you have control over from the PHP level.

Comment: Check settings for Outgoing mail mode in Tools and Settings > Mail Server Settings. It's possible to change the IP for outgoing emails sent by the mail server there.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately a solution was found - while placing the bindto parameter within the options object passed to stream_context_create within PHPMailer's connect method definition was not permitted by PHP for an unknown reason - setting that directly when calling the method did work, like this:

```
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
            'socket' => array(
            'bindto' => "specificIP:0",
            ),
    );
```